# Does changing attributes of a DOM object in an array remove that object from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I get an array of DOM objects using `getElementsByClassName`:

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
```

At this point, suppose `a.length` is `3`. Then, during some function call, I want to switch the attributes of some of these objects by changing their class names. For example, I modify the class name of `a[0]`:

```
a[0].className = "bar";
```

It seems that the object that was just called as `a[0]` is now removed from `a`. `a.length` is now `2`.

I am wondering why this happened. I defined `a` for once, but later modifications to its elements seem to be affecting the memberships of `a`. Can someone explain this?

Comment: I learned from pimvdb that the `a` above was actually not an array but was a NodeList, and that gave this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you collect the elements with querySelectorAll, the object that contains them will not be live, and represents a snapshot of the webpage. You could also remove the 'liveness' by turning the node list into an ordinary array-

```
a= [].slice.call(a,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for even providing a solution. You solution is elegant, and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#td-live) the `NodeList` (a kind of magical array) you obtain is *live*.

> NodeList and NamedNodeMap objects in the DOM are *live*; that is, changes to the underlying document structure are reflected in all relevant NodeList and NamedNodeMap objects.
>
> For example, if a DOM user gets a NodeList object containing the children of an Element, then subsequently adds more children to that element (or removes children, or modifies them), **those changes are automatically reflected in the NodeList**, without further action on the user's part.

Comment: Thank you, you made the point clear to me, and is a perfect answer, but I accepted kennebec's answer because it further gave me a solution, and it was exactly what I wanted.